# Does this thought experiment proves that Standard Quantum Mechanics and Pilot Wave Theory make different predictions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, decoherence, bohmian-mechanics, quantum-measurements

Here is a thought experiment that is supposed to show that standard quantum mechanics and pilot wave theory do not make the same prediction :

> Take the double slit experiment, and add a detector in each slit.
>
> In Standard Quantum Mechanics, the wave function will collapse by entering one slit. If the wave function collapse, it can no longer interfere with itself. Therefore, there won't be any interference pattern on the screen.
>
> With pilot wave theory, measurement has no effect on the state of the particle. Interference pattern will still appear on the screen.

I know that both theories should predict the same result, but I can't find what is wrong in this thought experiment.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: In pilot wave measurement can affect both the pilot wave and particle. In this case the relevant thing is interaction with the pilot wave.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I know what to search next :)

Comment: Max Born,an eminent pre-war physicist, said that the wave function does not describe a physical system but merely describes our knowledge of it. This resolves the paradox of Schrodinger's cat. Born was far from being the only one to hold this view..